# Can WIndows 8 boot by BIOS?

Tags: windows, bios, uefi

I have not yet owned a computer with UEFI support. From unreliable source I heard that Windows 8 may boot by BIOS.

However I conducted an experiment on a friend's PC, I turned UEFI off and Windows 8 did not boot.

Does it mean Windows 8 has to boot by UEFI?

Thank you!

Comment: Windows 8 must be installed on a computer using BIOS rather than UEFI for it to be able to boot from BIOS.  Moving from one to the other without a reinstall will not work.

Comment: It's actually possible to switch from BIOS to EFI booting; see https://gitorious.org/tianocore_uefi_duet_builds/pages/Windows_x64_BIOS_to_UEFI for details (ignore the stuff about DUET). Doing the opposite is presumably also possible, but I don't have a URL handy with instructions. As a practical matter, re-installing may be easier, especially for novices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Windows 8 will boot using BIOS. (Source: I am running Windows 8 on a motherboard that does not have UEFI capabilities.)

If Windows 8 was installed using UEFI, it may only boot using UEFI (though, I can not guarantee the accuracy of this).

Comment: Ditto. +1 (extra characters to make this allowed).

Comment: I see, so the laptop did not boot because Windows 8 was pre-installed when UEFI was enabled. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes of course it can be installed on non-UEFI systems, as long as all [requirements](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/system-requirements) are met. It would be silly of Microsoft if they relied on only new PC buyers or those with UEFI-based systems to drive sales of their latest OS. Only the **Secure Boot** feature and [booting from GPT partitioned disks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463525.aspx) requires UEFI (well technically GPT booting doesn't *require* UEFI, but 32-bit versions of Windows simply don't support it).